# ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL Intent not being received on HTC inspire

Tags: android

I have an app that listens for the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL Intent that has been working just fine on many devices running Android but now I just got an HTC Inspire and this intent is never received on that device? It seems as though this one particular phone doesn't send this intent out and outgoing calls go directly to the droids cell in-call screen i.e., can not be intercepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem in case someone else may run into it..

I was dynamically registering for the NEW OUTGOING CALL intent (as done for other intents my broadcast receiver gets). I found that if I statically registered for this intent via the app manifest it worked. I Don't know why only the HTC Inspiron had a problem with the dynamic registration but it did. I have tested this on probably a dozen different Android phones (including several HTC phones) and never had an issue.